# Redirect to create method of RegisterController in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I Wanted to redirect to create method of registerController in laravel after a particular action.

So that the user can login after the registration is complete

[the screenshoot of the Corresponding error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUfdR.png)

Comment: dont paste images of TEXT, paste the actual text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the default `RegisterController` provided by Laravel.

`create` is a protected method, so you cannot use it as an action in a Route; you may only use public methods there.

The public methods that are meant as route actions in the default implementation are:

- `showRegistrationForm`
- `register` (this one calls `create` internally)

So either redirect him to the Route that has `showRegistrationForm` as action - the user may then fill out the form, submit it, and is registered.

Or programmatically create the user in your particular action using `User::create()`. You can even use the returned/created `User` object to programmatically login the user in the current session using `Auth::login()`:

```php
// Creates the record in the database. $newUser returned by the create method is the created User object.
$newUser = \App\User::create([
    'email' => 'foo@bar.com',
    'password' => bcrypt('thepasswordforthenewuser'),
]);
// Pass to the SessionGuard to log him in.
\Auth::login($newUser);
```

Comment: Okay got it, Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell me how to return/created user and use Auth::login($user)

Comment: [https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authenticating-users] I think this works